# How to install `gstreamer0.1-ffmpeg` on ubuntu (17.10) artful?

Tags: video, 17.10, qt, h264

I get the following message whenever i want to play a `.mp4*` movie using a movie player I've written by `Qt 5.9.1` and `QtMultimedia` module:

> Warning: "No decoder available for type 'video/x-h264, level=(string)4, profile=

According to [offical Qt form](https://forum.qt.io/post/235035) Qt uses `gstreamer0.10` and specially `gstreamer0.1-ffmpeg` for decoding `h264`.

The problem is I can't find `gstreamer0.1-ffmpeg` in the main repository or any third-party ppa. How can I install it or is there any other workaround for Ubuntu artful?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*gstreamer1.0-libav* supports mp4 and video/x-h264 in Ubuntu 17.10 and later. To install it open the terminal and type:

```
sudo apt install gstreamer1.0-libav
```

Comment: VLC and mpv can play H.264 videos out of the box.